# Как получить логин пользователя в models или views

Tags: python, django, request

Я новичок в Django, не могу сообразить, как через request получить логин пользователя. Делаю сайт типа словаря, и нужно, чтобы каждая добавленная запись помечалась тем, кто ее добавил.

Вот мой models.py

```
from django.db import models

class EngDict(models.Model):

    orig_word = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False,blank=False, verbose_name='Слово')
    translate = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False, verbose_name="Перевод")
    remarks = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Примечания")
    published_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Добавлено")
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Дата добавления")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name = 'Категория')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Перевод")
        verbose_name_plural = "Англо-русский словарь"
        ordering = ['-published_date']
```

А это views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from .models import EngDict, Category
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import EngDictForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, FormView
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login

class EngDictCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'dict/create.html'
    form_class = EngDictForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Я так понимаю, мне надо написать функцию типа def user_name(request) , но я не могу сообразить где должна быть эта функция и как она должна выглядеть. Мне по идее надо, чтобы в published_by автоматом подставлялся логин пользователя при создании новой записи.

Comment: В модели нет поля с внешним ключом на модель пользователя, как вы планируете хранить эти данные?

Comment: Честно говоря, не совсем понял вопрос. Мне надо, чтобы значением published_by стало имя пользователя. А хранится всё в базе данных же. Если я добавлю Внешний ключ, то появится выпадающий список со всеми пользователями.

Comment: Выпадающий список не проблема спрятать, это во-первых. Во-вторых, модель ничего не должна знать про текущего пользователя, потому что это нарушает абстракцию. Следует передать нужного пользователя в модель явно, из вьюхи или типа того

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не надо никаких функций, пользователя из реквеста можно получить через `request.user`. Но вам в комментариях абсолютно правильно указали, что лучше бы связать поле published_by с моделью пользователя внешним ключом, иначе потом придётся создавать костыли на простейшие задачи.